# Background fade in on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying get this background to fade in on click. I found one tutorial that was helpful, and I ended up created the code so it has two images, and they fade in and out on click to bring up the picture. 
Here's the work: http://www.mccraymusic.com/bgchangetest.html

Only a couple of issues though:

1. How do I make this work without the images getting selected at random? I'd like it to just switch from the plain black image to the image with the drum set. (And cross-fade to if possible, but not necessary)
2. How do I center the image on the page, so the image of the drums are centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you're after:

```
$(function() {
    var images = ["black.jpg","bg.jpg"];
    $('<img>').attr({'src':'http://www.mccraymusic.com/assets/images/'+images[0],'id':'bg','alt':''}).appendTo('#bg-wrapper').parent().fadeIn(0);

    $('.entersite').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var image = images[1];
        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('#bg').attr('src', 'http://www.mccraymusic.com/assets/images/'+image); 
              $(this).fadeIn(1000);
        });
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});​
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/GewXh/2/)

Also added :

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

to your `#bg` element to center the image.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, that's the effect! The background still won't center though.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, assuming you use JQuery
You have #backgroundid and #imageid
Begin by setting

```
$('#backgroundid').css('opacity',1);
$('#imageid').css('opacity',0); // setting opacity (transparency) to 0, invisible
```

Now you have #buttonid.
Set up a jquery event so that when it's clicked, you fade out the background, and fade in the image using JQuery's animate.

```
$('#buttonid').click(function() {
    $('#backgroundid').animate(function() {
        opacity : 0 // fade it to 0 opacity, invisible
    }, 1000); // animation will take 1000ms, 1second
    $('#imageid').animate(function() {
        opacity : 1 // fade it to full opacity, solid
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Now about that image centering.**
You can either let **css** manage it with

```
body { /* Body or #imageid parent */
    text-align : center;
}
#imageid {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Or you can stick to a **JQuery** solution, using absolute/fixed positioning.
First, use some css to fix the position of your image

```
#imageid {
    position: absolute; // or fixed, if you want
}
```

Now use JQuery to reposition it

```
function positionImage() {
    var imagewidth = $('#imageid').width();
    var imageheight = $('#imageid').height();
    $('#imageid').css('left', ($(window).width() - imagewidth) / 2);
    $('#imageid').css('top', ($(window).height() - imageheight) / 2);
}
$(document).ready(positionImage); // bind the ready event to reposition
$(window).resize(positionImage); // on window resize, reposition image too
```

Answer (score 0):

if you keep a div element with height and width as 100% and bgcolor as black. And then change the opacity of the div as desired to get the fade in/out effect, that should generate the same effect. I guess..

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using any available jQuery plugin as they would have optimized and fixed bugs for multiple browsers.

Try lightBoxMe plugin 
http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/

This is the simplest plugin available!